# What could cause a program to stay in "Add/Remove Programs" even after removing from registry

Tags: windows-server-2008, windows-registry, 32-bit

Trying to manually remove an entry from  Control Panel > Add/Remove Programs.

(custom software, not MS KB patch or windows component and not doing anyting 'funky' like trying to stop itself form being uninstalled)

Followed http://support.microsoft.com/kb/314481 removing all applicable registry keys for program from

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\
```

and even tried rebooting but still it persists. Double checked followed KB314481 and search for program name doesn't return any other matches in that part of the registry.

Any ideas what would cause this or how to solve?

Answer (score 1):

Most often when I've seen this behavior there are still entries under the uninstall key buried under a GUID independent from the main entry containing the program name. I usually just do a search starting at the uninstall key for the desired text to find the right GUID and kill it off.

Comment: Done that searching on program name but no sign under that /Uninstall key.